# Load font from css file using html in android

Tags: android, html, css

I have to change only one line to Uthmanic font.I have tried the below code.But the uthmani font wasn't loaded till now.

I have added the Uthmani font to the folder : assets->articles->UthmanicHafs.ttf

**done.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

 <p > Url to load contents </p>

 <p class="uth">Change this text </p>    --->change to uthmani font for this one line

 </body>
```

**style.css:**

```
body {
    margin: 15px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(opensans.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Uthmani';
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('Uthmani'), local('Uthmani'), url(UthmanicHafs.ttf) format('ttf');
}


.uth {
   font-family: 'Uthmani'
   font-size: 100px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

I dont know why the uthmani font wasn't loaded.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the path to your font. Place the desired OTF or TTF font in `assets/fonts` and define the path as following in your css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyFont;
    src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyFont.otf")
}
```

If your font isn't a latin font, try to convert the font from otf to svg! There were some discussions and bug reports about this issue, but google never responded - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Use a online converter like [Everything Fonts](https://everythingfonts.com/) and you'll be good. Be sure that the namespace includes `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`!

Comment: I have also added this in my style.css file but it's not working @Mibit

Answer (score 0):

For android and other mobile devices you need an .svg type of your font. Please use it with media queries.